# get last element from a sentence in span using selenium python

Tags: python, selenium

I want to scrape last word of a sentence defined in a span using selenium python. I am able to get the whole sentence using this:-

```
elements = browser.find_element_by_css_selector("span[ng-if='!product.product.isOnlyCarCategory']");
print elements
result = elements.text
print result
```

Output:- `Buy for Rs 329`

I want only 329 to be output not the whole sentence.
I've tried using replace function of python and able to achieve what I want like this:-

```
elements = browser.find_element_by_css_selector("span[ng-if='!product.product.isOnlyCarCategory']");
print elements
result = elements.text
result = int(result.replace('Buy for Rs ',''))
print result
```

Output:- `329`

but I don't want to use replace function. I want to use selenium to do the same.
And yes this integer value is dynamic

Is there any way to do that?

Comment: Why dont you just `split` the string by space and get the last element?

Comment: @Abbas yeah i can use that but what if the website will change their span text in future. Then it will not work

Comment: you can catch the numeric value after Rs with regex and replace the whole string with that

Comment: @dnit13 okay. Can you tell me how to do that?

Comment: So, do you want to find the last number or the last word?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/713798/regex-to-find-a-number-in-a-string

Comment: @Ni. I want to find the number from this string which is at the last

Answer (score 0):

You can use a regex, or a for loop instead:

```
strNum = ""
for c in result[::-1]:
    if c.isdigit():
        strNum=c+strNum
    elif len(strNum)>0:
        break
num=into(strNum)
print num
```